# How to use the sequence_length parameter in TensorFlowRNNClassifier() from skflow?

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

I'm doing text classification using RNN. Text documents have varying length, therefore I would like to be able to specify sequence length when training the RNN. I noticed the [sequence_length parameter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/rnn.py) in TensorFlowRNNClassifier() from skflow package, but do not know how to use it.

Suppose a batch of data consists of three documents of length 10, 20, and 30, what should the sequence_length parameter be? Just to be clear, I'm aware that we can set max_document_length to 30 and patch the first two documents with 0s, but I'd like to do dynamic sequences.

Thank you very much!